# Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource. Telerik Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, treeview

Im getting this error while trying to giva my treeview an itemsource
"Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."

I have checked a lot of solutions and I cant seem to find a way to solve this. Here are my code snippets:

XAML:

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Category">

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
            </TextBlock>

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

XAML

```
<telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="treeview" IsDragDropEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Margin="10,10,0,-3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" IsManipulationEnabled="True" IsLoadOnDemandEnabled="True" LoadOnDemand="treeview_LoadOnDemand" IsExpandOnSingleClickEnabled="True"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Category}">               
        </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

C# - Giving the treeview a data source:

```
 Data d = new Data();
        treeview.ItemsSource = d.Get_Categories();
```

C# - My database query:

```
 public List<Category> Get_Categories()
    {

            using (var context = new ProcessDatabaseEntities())
            {
                return context.Category.ToList();
            }

    }
```

Category only has two properties, Name and ID. I know that the itemsource-list is not empty when I assign it. So it's probably something wrong with my XAML-code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wheres the method `treeview_LoadOnDemand`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is a common one. Basically, you cannot use both the `TreeView.ItemsSource` and the `TreeView.Items` properties together... you *must* choose one way or the other. Usually this problem manifests itself because a developer has done something like this...:

```
<TreeView Name="TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" ... />
```

... and then tried to do something like this in the code behind:

```
TreeView.Items.Add(someItem);
```

The solution in that case would be to manipulate the data bound collection instead of the `TreeView.Items` collection:

```
SomeCollection.Add(someItem);
```

However, in your case (and it's a little bit difficult to guess without seeing your code), you have probably done the second part first (set or manipulated the `Items` property) and then tried to set the `ItemsSource` property. Your solution is the same... use one method of editing the items or the other... not both.